# How to return just applications from package manager?

Tags: android

Can the type of application be determined from the ApplicationInfo object ?

By type I mean, determine if is a widget or application.

Alternatively can just a List of of applications which does not include widgets be returned from getPackageManager()?
Below code is what I'm trying to return just applications
but widgets are returned also:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> appInfoList = context.getPackageManager()
        .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can query just the app with or without widgets. But what you can do is to check `ActivityInfo.metaData` field of every registered broadcast receiver. It contains an instance of `Bundle` class. All receivers having a widget must have a metadata with the name `android.appwidget.provider` in that bundle.

```
final PackageManager pm = act.getPackageManager(); 
final Intent widgetIntent = new Intent("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
final List<ResolveInfo> receivers = pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(widgetIntent,
        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

// optional part (see note below)
for (ResolveInfo receiver : receivers) {
    ActivityInfo info = receiver.activityInfo;
    if (info.metaData != null) {
        boolean hasWidget = info.metaData.containsKey("android.appwidget.provider");
        if (hasWidget) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Package %s has widget",
                    info.packageName));
        }
    }
}
```

*Note*: It might even be enough to query all receivers responding to `"android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"` action without checking for metadata, because those receivers are intended for serving a widget. We can assume if there is a receiver with such action, then these is a widget. You don't need the for-loop then.

Comment: "All applications having a widget must have a metadata with the name android.appwidget.provider" what attribute of Bundle class is this information contained in ?